# How to pass python api endpoint to Kubernates CronJob

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, cron

This is first time I am encountering jobs running in react+python+kubernates project, so please allow me for thinking as a newbie.

Problem statement-

I have created an api endpoint in python and wanted that endpoint run in every 30 minutes as a job. The recommendation is, to use Cronjob by Kubernetes.

Here is some code snippet:

In `main.py`

```
@api.post("/fetchAllStudentProfile")
def import_all_student_data():
    
    print("\r\nSchedular starts on - %s" % datetime.now())

 // reads connection string about source(a database) from config.py
    jobConfig = config.read_jobConfig_file()

 // get all data from source and save into local db
   student_data= read_data.get_all_data(jobConfig)
```

Now I want this to pass to already written cron_job which is expecting in following format:

```
 <cron_job_name> 
  params= job_name_as_key , start_time
```

So, I am not getting what/how to pass params ( *job_name_as_key* and *start_time* ) in import_all_student_data() method.

References: [Cron Jobs in K8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192053/cron-jobs-in-kubernetes-connect-to-existing-pod-execute-script) [medium link](https://medium.com/@pandit.summit/kubernetes-cron-job-with-python-image-in-minikube-windows-10-ac33851d573d)

TIA